# Using "group by" and "having" in a query

Tags: mysql

I like to write query something similar below where column xX_role count of row more that 1. How do I do this. Below is something similar I am trying to do. I am trying to filter data with similar column values.

```
Select
  scrs.requestid,
  scr_remedy,
  type,
  workstream,
  system,
  status,
  scrs.release,
  assigned_to,
  `role`,
  LEFT(role, 7) as 'xx_role',
  MID(role, 5,3) as 'roleid'
from
  scrs,
  tblscr_role 
GROUP BY 'xx_role'
HAVING
  (scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid)
  and (scrs.release = 'GROUP6' OR scrs.release = 'ER_JUNE15' OR scrs.release = 'ER_APR_15')
  and Count('xx_role') > 1
```

Comment: At the simplest level, it is a matter of quoting. Removing the single quotes from `xx_role` will have some effect, but possibly not return the desired result still.  I notice there's no joining condition between those two tables, or there is in HAVING but it belongs in WHERE.  In any case, using `'xx_role'` with quotes is causing MySQL to interpret it as a literal string rather than an alias/identifier.

Comment: For us to answer confidently with a working query, it would help to have a sample of input rows together with a sample of the output rows you are hoping to get from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what @MichaelBerkowski mentioned, you are very likely abusing the notorious MySQL extension to GROUP BY.  Read this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

You also have a promiscuous join in `from scrs, tblsc_role`. Join conditions in HAVING clauses don't do what you think they will.

```
Select
  scrs.requestid,
  scr_remedy,
  type,
  workstream,
  system,
  status,
  scrs.release,
  assigned_to,
  `role`,
  LEFT(role, 7) as xx_role,
  MID(role, 5,3) as roleid
 from scrs
 join tblscr_role ON scrs.requestid = tblscr_role.requestid
where (    scrs.release = 'GROUP6'
        OR scrs.release = 'ER_JUNE15'
        OR scrs.release = 'ER_APR_15')
```

Once you get the detail results you need from that query, you can go ahead and add the GROUP BY / HAVING clauses. But try to use a standard GROUP BY.